# Spotify API: Album name appears multiple times in a single query

Tags: api, uri, spotify

I am receiving several multiple album names from the query listed below. I want to know if there is a way of receiving only one instance of the album name.

http://ws.spotify.com/lookup/1/?uri=spotify:artist:3TVXtAsR1Inumwj472S9r4&extras=album

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no.

Artists very often have multiple releases of the same album, for various reasons. Normally, it's slightly different versions of the album for different areas of the world - indeed, in the example you give the `territories` key has different values for each duplicate.

Depending on your use case, you need to deal with this correctly. If you're suggesting albums for a user to listen to, you need to make sure the album is available in the territory the user is in.

If you're just listing albums on a static page and not linking to them, putting the list of names though a set to thin out the duplicates would be sufficient.